# Hey I am trying to convert this c++ to javascript and something doesnt work

Tags: javascript, c++

So I have this c++ code with a factorial function and some other stuff and I am trying to convert it to JavaScript

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int n){ //Aprēķina skaitļa faktoriali izsaucot pati sevi

  if(n > 1)
     return n*factorial(n - 1);
  else
     return 1;
}

int main(){
  int ok;
  do{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    int x=factorial(n);
    cout << "factorial=" << x << endl;
    for(int a=1;(a+2)<(x/2+1);a++){ // Pilda līdz trešais skaitlis sasniedz pusi no faktoriala
        if(a*(a+1)*(a+2)==x) cout << "Equals " << a << "*" << a+1 << "*" << a+2 << endl;
      }
    cout << " Vai turpinat (1) vai beigt (Ievadi 0)?" << endl;
    cin >> ok;
  }
  while (ok==1);
}
```

And I have gotten this far with my JavaScript code but I cant work out what doesnt quite work

```
<script>
var factorial(var n){ //Aprēķina skaitļa faktoriali izsaucot pati sevi
    if(n > 1)
        return n*factorial(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}
do{
   var n = Number(prompt(Ievadi naturālu skaitli))
    var x=factorial(n);
    window.alert(+x" ir šī skaitļa pirmskaitlis ");
    for(var a=1;(a+2)<(x/2+1);a++){ // Pilda līdz trešais skaitlis sasniedz pusi no faktoriala
        if(a*(a+1)*(a+2)==x) window.alert(" equals"+a"*"a+1"*"a+2);
      }
    var ok == (" Vai turpinat (1) vai beigt (0)?"));
  }
  while (ok==1);
}
</script>
```

I quite dont get javascript so it may seem i have a some stupid mistakes but please go easy on me I am new to this, thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error you're running into?

Comment: How *does* it work? What happens when the Javascript code runs? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It doesnt display anything just a blank page

Comment: There's nothing in the developer console either? I can already see an error where you have a `)` too many for your variable `ok`, that should show up.

Comment: Expression expected (3,5) and (9,4) and (13,9) and Identifier expected at (12,23)

Comment: `var factorial(var n)` should be `function factorial(n)`, there are other errors.

Comment: @RobG could you please point them out? I would really appreciate it

Comment: `var ok == (" Vai turpinat (1) vai beigt (0)?"));` What's this supposed to do?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It asks the user if he wants to repeat the program(1) or if he wants to end it(0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got pretty close, hopefully the comments are sufficient:

```js
//Aprēķina skaitļa faktoriali izsaucot pati sevi
// Functions are declared with the function keyword
// Parameters are implicitly declared
function factorial(n) {
  // Use braces for clarity
  if (n > 1) {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}

do {
  // No need for Number, the factorial function will coerce the value to Number using * and -
  // Quote string literals
  var n = prompt('Ievadi naturālu skaitli');
  var x = factorial(n);
  // Fix string literal
  window.alert(x + ' ir šī skaitļa pirmskaitlis');
  // Pilda līdz trešais skaitlis sasniedz pusi no faktoriala
  for (var a = 1; (a + 2) < (x / 2 + 1); a++) { 
    if (a * (a + 1) * (a + 2) == x) {
      // Fix string literal
      window.alert('Equals ' + a + '*' + (a + 1) + '*' + (a + 2));
    }
  }
  // == is comparison, = is assignment
  // Don't forget prompt( ... )
  var ok = prompt('Vai turpinat (1) vai beigt (0)?');
} while (ok == 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is fixed code:

```
function factorial(n){ //Aprēķina skaitļa faktoriali izsaucot pati sevi
    if(n > 1)
        return n*factorial(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}
do{
   var n = Number(prompt("Ievadi naturālu skaitli"))
    var x=factorial(n);
    window.alert(x + " ir šī skaitļa pirmskaitlis ");
    for(var a=1;(a+2)<(x/2+1);a++){ // Pilda līdz trešais skaitlis sasniedz pusi no faktoriala
        if(a*(a+1)*(a+2)==x) window.alert(" equals"+a +"*"+(a+1)+"*"+(a+2));
      }
    var ok = prompt(" Vai turpinat (1) vai beigt (0)?");
}
while (ok==1);
```